# How do you globally disable Angular animations based on media query in a standalone app?

Tags: angular, animation, media-queries, angular-standalone-components

It's previously been possible to disable animations in the whole app based on a media query:

```js
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppRootComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule.withConfig({
      disableAnimations: window.matchMedia("(prefers-reduced-motion)").matches, // <-
    }),
    // ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

With the new provider pattern, the module import is changed to [`provideAnimations`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/provideAnimations):

```js
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
    // ...
  ]
});
```

[This](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/provideAnimations), however, doesn't accept any configurations like previously.

There seems to be [a `provideNoopAnimations` alternative](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/provideNoopAnimations), but I don't see how you dynamically change which provider to use, based on a media query (`prefers-reduced-motion`)

How is this achieved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can actually be done very simply using the two new providers and resolving the media query inline/through a variable:

```
const disableAnimations: boolean = window.matchMedia(
  "(prefers-reduced-motion: reduce)"
).matches;

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    !disableAnimations ? provideAnimations() : provideNoopAnimations(),
    // ...
  ]
});
```